# Instantiate a template class at run time in terms of different types

Tags: c++, templates

The program is organized as follow:

1. First it reads a files where the *type* information is contained.
2. It has to instantiate a class according to that type.

For instance, if `type = float`, I have to instantiate an object `A<float> a`.

Currently I handle this work by plain `if-else` statements.

```
if (type == "float") {
    A<float> a;
}
```

I am wondering if there are some ways to handle a type just like a variable or something else, which let me create the object by `A<specific_type> a` without judgement?

Comment: How about a map with a string key and function pointer value?

Comment: _"which let me create the object by `A<specific_type> a` without judgement?"_ So you mean by just using another tempate parameter that is filled in from a variable available at runtime? Then the answer is no, templates are instantiated at compile time.

Comment: @MohitJain, that seems to be an acceptable way.

Comment: No because `type` is not known until runtime, but in C++ templates are instantiated at **compile-time**. If you only have a few different `types` to read, then you're basically on the right track with an if-else. But if you have alot of different types of classes to instantiate, you may want to consider using a standardized way to create/save/load data structures such as XML (if your project allows it)

Comment: @ruffles _" I don't know if C++ can do this"_ C++ doesn't support standardized runtime reflection mechanisms so far. Some reflection can be done at compile time through type traits.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Every computer science problem can be solved by another layer of indirection.

Comment: Voted to close as unclear because the key information, what you intend to *do* with the instantiated object, is missing. As presented the question is both trivial and utterly meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking for something like this?

```
template <class A>
void workWithA(void)
{ 
   A a ;
}

std::map<std::string, void (*f_ptr)(void)> functions ;

functions["float"] = &workWithA<float> ;
functions["int"] = &workWithA<int> ;
...
```

then you can write

```
std::string type ;
auto it = functions.find(type) ;
if (it != functions.end())
     it->second() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't instantiate template with parameters changing at runtime.

Templates are processed when compiled. How your program would deal with it if it doesn't know what it is manipulating ?

There still could be a solution if you embark a tool chain with your program that generate a lib from your file that you could use... But I don't know if that is worth the effort.

Comment: Well, I understand the point. But the things is, I feel that too many `if-else` statements are ugly to some extent...So I want to see if your guys have clever solutions?

Comment: @chain XY problem. Too many if statements are ugly, therefore I have to instantiate templates at run time, I better ask how to do that... wrong, you want to ask how to get rid of ugly if statements.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question directly (why do you need to instantiate a templated class at runtime?) but here's one possibility...

If there are too many different types of classes, and if you have control of the format of data file, you could consider using something like XML (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML). There should be XML libraries available for c++ that would allow you to load file data of any kind of complex structure, manipulate it in c++, then save it back to a file. There would be a small performance hit but for most applications this wouldn't be noticeable.